# Create a Custom Event Behavior in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

In Xcode 4.1 in Preferences->Behaviors tab you can perform certain actions on certain events, build failed, build starts, etc..

Is there a way to add your own events?  There is a plus icon at the bottom to add events, but I can't find any documentation on how to do it.  I can create a new event but from there I don't know how to hook it up.

I'd like to be able to run a script after I commit changes.
The only documentation I found is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-alerts_preferences/Recipe.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XCode 4.1 a custom behavior can only be triggered by a keyboard shortcut, not an event (like commit completed).

You could create a "Commit Completed" behavior to run your script, hook it up to a keyboard shortcut, then hit that shortcut after each commit.