# Can I make Xcode switch to Project navigator after a Commit completes?

Tags: xcode, commit, git-commit

After a Commit, Xcode leaves the Source Control navigator selected.  I'm done with source control, so I'd like Xcode to switch to the Project navigator.  Is there a way to automate this?

I did something similar for running.  After running, Xcode leaves the Debug navigator selected (if I set break points).  I made Xcode switch to the Project navigator after running by setting: Behaviors > Running > Completes > Show > navigator Project.

Behaviors doesn't have a built-in Commit section.  I tried adding a new behavior.  Xcode creates a "Custom" category, but I don't know how to tie this to Commit (if it's even possible).

#### Update

I found an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7072946/2526464).  It appears you can only attach events to the built-in behaviors (Commit is not one of them).  Otherwise, you can create a custom behavior to assign a script to a keyboard shortcut.  Since there is already a keyboard shortcut to switch to the Project navigator (Command+1), it's not worth it for me.

Comment: IDK, but it's fairly easy to jump to the Project Navigator with CMD+1.

Comment: @dominicoder I agree, but I'm always looking to save a keystroke.